# Why APT Preferences doesn't work as expect

Tags: preferences, apt

I want to install puppet which version higher than 2.7.11 on Ubuntu, but the origin source version is 2.7.11, so I add the puppetlabs's source:

```
echo "deb http://apt.puppetlabs.com precise devel" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/puppetlabs.list
```

then I use apt-get and then find the latest version is already 3.0.0 .But I just want to use 2.7.19 .So I edit the /etc/apt/preferences:

```
package:puppet
Pin: release  v=2.7.19*, o= "http://apt.puppetlabs.com/"
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

then I use apt-cache policy puppet ,but it seems this does not works as I expect:

```
puppet:
Installed: 3.0.0-0.1rc6puppetlabs1
Candidate: 3.0.0-0.1rc6puppetlabs1
Package pin: (not found)
Version table:
*** 3.0.0-0.1rc6puppetlabs1 1001
    500 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ precise/devel amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.7.19-0.1rc3puppetlabs1 1001
    500 http://apt.puppetlabs.com/ precise/devel amd64 Packages
```

I have read the man 5 apt_preferences, but still can't make it works right.

Comment: This question belongs in http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: I would suggest unix&linux instead, since this isn't specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

Read the file [here](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/dists/squeeze/Release)

The `"o="` means the Origin in the Release file.
If you want to use `http`  (as the source in sources.list)... you should write:

```
Pin: origin "http..."
```

Check at man apt_preferences to get more help about it!

Comment: How can I set version 2.7.19 to the 1001 ,adn keep other version in the 500 at the same time?